# What does "a fait état" mean here?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I encountered this phrase in an article from Le Monde about an earthquake in Iraq.

> Un premier bilan diffusé par la télévision d’Etat iranienne a fait état de six morts dans la ville-frontière de Qasr-e Shirin.
>
> A first report released by Iranian state television _______ six deaths in the border town of Qasr-e Shirin.

I know that "a fait" is the 3rd sg. passé composée of faire. Thus literally it means "has done" or "has made". But I don't recognize the next word, état, which is normally a noun meaning "state".

How do these three words work together to signify the intended meaning, "reported" or "announced"?

Comment: Once again, "faire état de" is a set phrase with the meaning of "mentionner / rapporter" in this context. You'll often hear it, along with these words: "Un **bilan** provisoire fait état de cinq **morts** et douze **blessés**."

Comment: This might help https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_%C3%A9tat

Comment: Why don't you guys set that as answers instead of comments?

Comment: @ON5MF Ça arrive quand il y a conflit entre l'idée de référence générale,  de l'effort de recherche de la personne qui demande, par rapport à l'idée de valeur ajoutée par le rendu différent et la diversité des réponses. C'est un vieux sujet, est-ce que « general reference » devrait mener à la fermeture. On ne veut pas que le site soit une copie de wiktionnaire ou wikipédia, mais en même temps on croit à la valeur ajoutée d'une réponse qui permettrait d'obtenir un éclairage différent sur un sujet connu. Il est parfois difficile de concilier ces impératifs. Merci.

Answer (score 3):

@Alone-zee's answer is correct. "faire état de" is a french saying used a lot in news broadcasts. It can be translated by "to mention" or "to report".

In your case, you could translate

> Un premier bilan diffusé par la télévision d’Etat iranienne **a fait état de** six morts dans la ville-frontière de Qasr-e Shirin.

by

> A first report released by Iranian state television **mentionned** six deaths in the border town of Qasr-e Shirin.